# gitlab-ci docker | using sudo inside container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, sudo, gitlab-ci-runner

Hey fellow developers,

I use gitlab-ci, with my own gitlab-runner running as a docker image on the server (Ubuntu 22.04, Docker 20.10, Docker image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest).

I want to use some `sudo` commands inside the container.

How can I do that ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions Please don't be a chameleon question.

Comment: I edit my question BEFORE the first answer so I feel legit in this way... but I cant re-edit and repost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install sudo from you docker file:

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker 
sudo

USER docker
CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: Ty for the fast answer, I did edit my post cause the problem evolved :p but ty and it may be usefull for me later on !

Comment: oh, If you want to transfer files from outside to docker container, I recommend you to use "VOLUME" in docker, it can mount a folder from outside to docker container